# How to make a text replacement in PHP?

Tags: php, string, replace, vbulletin

so im adding commands to a very popular vbulletin plugin, and there's this one i cant seem to get to work properly no matter what i try.  The code i have so far is

```
$cybcb_checkban = strpos($vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage'], '/ban');
                if($cybcb_checkban !== false AND $cybcb_candelall)
                {
                    $banuserurl = $vbulletin->options['bburl'].'/misc.php?'.$vbulletin->session->vars['sessionurl'].'do=ccb_banuser&u=2';exec_header_redirect($banuserurl);
                }
```

what i need it to do is the part that says

```
do=ccb_banuser&u=2
```

is replace the **2** with the text entered in my chat.

vbulletin kinda has its own language but the base concept of it is PHP
but for reference, this is a default command already in the plugin

```
$cybcb_checkme = strpos($vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage'], '/me ');
                if ($cybcb_checkme !== false)
                {
                    $vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage'] = str_replace('/me ', $vbulletin->userinfo['username'].' ', $vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage']);
                    $vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage'] = '[color='.$vbulletin->options['cybchatbox_mecolor'].']* '.$vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage'].'[/color]';
                }
```

I've been playing around with this for a few days now, and the only result I've got semi working is the first code at the top, the problem with that as you may have guess by entering

```
/ban (USER ID HERE)
```

the only user that will get banned is user 2 (obviously)

so i just need something that will give the code the ability to be /ban (userID)

i know its got to be something like

```
$banuserurl = $vbulletin->options['bburl'].'/misc.php?'.$vbulletin->session->vars['sessionurl'].'do=ccb_banuser&u=.$vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage']';exec_header_redirect($banuserurl);
```

but that doesnt seem to work =/  anyone have the answer? or can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful =) thanks.

Comment: missed the single quotation mark after &u= `ccb_banuser&u=.$vbulletin->` and odd last one.

Answer (score 0):

`$vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage']` will contain the whole message, so if you send
`/ban 123455`

`$vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage']` will have `/ban 123455`
what you can then do is remove '/ban ' and you'll be left with the User ID

so something like

```
$cybcb_checkban = strpos($vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage'], '/ban');
                if($cybcb_checkban !== false AND $cybcb_candelall)
                {
                    $vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage'] = str_replace('/ban ', '', $vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage']);
                    $banuserurl = $vbulletin->options['bburl'].'/misc.php?'.$vbulletin->session->vars['sessionurl'].'do=ccb_banuser&u=' . $vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage'];
                    exec_header_redirect($banuserurl);
                }
```

or

```
$cybcb_checkban = strpos($vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage'], '/ban');
                if($cybcb_checkban !== false AND $cybcb_candelall)
                {
                    $banuserurl = $vbulletin->options['bburl'].'/misc.php?'.$vbulletin->session->vars['sessionurl'].'do=ccb_banuser&u=' . substr($vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage'], 4);
                    exec_header_redirect($banuserurl);
                }
```

should work

note: that 4 should probably be replaced with something like `substr($vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage'], strpos($vbulletin->GPC['ccb_newmessage'], '/ban') + strlen('/ban'));`